# Counting bridge hands argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is as follows:

What is wrong with the following argument, which purports to show that $4C(39,13)$ bridge hands contain three or fewer suits?

"There are $C(39,13)$ that contain only clubs, diamonds, and spades. In fact, for any three suits, there are $C(39,13)$ hands that contain only those three suits. Since there are four 3-combinations of the suits, the answer is $4C(39,13)$."

I am having trouble understanding what it is the argument is saying, why are we choosing from $39$ cards instead of $52$? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: A hand containing no hearts is formed by 13 cards, chosen from 39 possible (52 cards minus 13 cards of hearts).

Comment: @Aretino ah I see, is the problem that we have repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider hands that have only hearts and spades.  You've counted all of these hands twice by considering the hands that are free of clubs, and those that are free of diamonds.

And the hands that are one suit only?  You've counted all of those three times.